# How do I get Ant Design's message working when I'm navigating away from my page with react-router's useNavigate?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, antd, react-apollo

I have an app that does the usual CRUD features, with a list page that will link to creating and editing a resource. Here's a visual:

```
List
|__Create
|__Edit
```

The create and edit forms share a very similar form, so i'm just reusing that.

My issue comes from when I create/edit something (this is working), I want to show [ant design's message](https://ant.design/components/message), and navigate back to my list page using [`useNavigate` from react-router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate). The problem is that when my create/edit is successful, in my success callback, when navigating, I'm not able to see the message pop up at all. However, the message pops up when I'm not navigating away.

My assumption is because maybe my message's `contextHolder` is on the create/edit page, navigating away will make me lose that, thus not being able to see it.

My async requests are using apollo graphql, so it looks like this

```
// CreateEditForm.tsx

const navigate = useNavigate();
const [messageApi, contextHolder] = message.useMessage();

// ....
onComplete: (data) => {
  if (!data.error) {
    return messageApi.error('Error');
  }

  messageApi.success('Success');
  return navigate('/list')
re
}

//.... in my CreateEditForm.tsx's render

return (
  <>
    {contextHolder}
    <Form>
    {/* the rest of my code */}
);
```

#### What I've tried

Since my assumption is that navigating away from the page is not making the message show, I tried extracting out the contextHolder to a level above in my list, but that didn't seem to work.

EDIT: I realized if I add async/await to `messageApi.success`, the message *will* appear for however long the default timeout is, *then* it will navigate. However, I was hoping for a more synchronous solution.

#### Minimal reproduction of this issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-tree-mysc4n?file=/src/AnotherPage.tsx

Has anyone faced a similar issue like this? Thank you in advance

Comment: "My assumption is because maybe my message's contextHolder is on the create/edit page, navigating away will make me lose that, thus not being able to see it." - This sounds logical and was also my guess that whatever this `messageApi` thing is only exists on the route you are currently on and that navigating away removes the handler logic. Can you [edit] to provide a complete [mcve] so we can actually see what the code does and when it does it?

Comment: @DrewReese Added an example in my original post!

Answer (score 1):

[As per documentation](https://ant.design/components/message#message-demo-hooks), the recommanded way to way to use message is to wrap your complete app with `Application wrapper (App)` and use message like this:

`const { message } = App.useApp();`.

Using App, you do not need to handle the contextHolder manually. Antd will take care of it.

Here's the complete code.

`index.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { App as AntdApp } from "antd";
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router";
import { AnotherPage } from "./AnotherPage";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")!;
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <App /> },
  { path: "/create", element: <AnotherPage /> }
]);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AntdApp>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AntdApp>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`AnotherPage.tsx`

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, App } from "antd";

export const AnotherPage = () => {
  const { message } = App.useApp();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Create Page</h3>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          message.success("Thing is created!");
          navigate("/");
        }}
      >
        Click to show msg and navigate back
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: It would be better to link to more relevant documentation that ***actually*** mentions/clarifies/explains this `App` import and usage, e.g. [App](https://ant.design/components/app). The link you used is the same that OP shared in their post, and it makes no mention of this `App` component.

Answer (score 0):

This `Message` API is a bit *interesting/odd* IMO, but I was able to get things working by moving the `message` usage into a layout route that exists above the main routes, and provides the `messageApi` via a React context.

Example:

Index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { message } from "antd";
import App from "./App";
import { AnotherPage } from "./AnotherPage";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")!;
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);
```

Create an `AppLayout` component to use the `useMessage` hook and provide the `contextHolder` to the UI and the `messageApi` to the `Outlet` context.

```
const AppLayout = () => {
  const [messageApi, contextHolder] = message.useMessage();

  return (
    <>
      {contextHolder}
      <Outlet context={{ messageApi }} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Render `AppLayout` as a layout route.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <App />
      },
      {
        path: "/create",
        element: <AnotherPage />
      }
    ]
  }
]);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

AnotherPage

Access the `messageApi` that is provided via the `Outlet`'s context provider.

```
import { useNavigate, useOutletContext } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "antd";

export const AnotherPage = () => {
  const { messageApi } = useOutletContext();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Create Page</h3>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          messageApi.success("Thing is created!");
          navigate(-1);
        }}
      >
        Click to show msg and navigate back
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-do-i-get-ant-designs-message-working-when-im-navigating-away-from-my-page]